# Identify values that appear a certain number of times in an R data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame of strings, most of which are duplicated. I would like to identify values in this data frame that occur at least x number of times.

```
   df <- data.frame(x = c("str", "str", "str", "ing", "ing","."))
   occurs <- 3
```

The data frame contains hundreds of unique strings, and tens of thousands of elements altogether. In this example, how I can identify which strings are occurring at least three times? Specifically, I would like to output the names of the strings that meet this criterion, not their indices in the data frame.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe `table` is what you need - here's a modified example based on your code:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c("str", "str", "str", "ing", "ing","."))
> df
    x
1 str
2 str
3 str
4 ing
5 ing
6   .
> table(df$x)

  . ing str 
  1   2   3 
> table(df$x) > 2

    .   ing   str 
FALSE FALSE  TRUE 
> names(which(table(df$x) > 2))
[1] "str"
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also use `count`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% count(x)
```

This will call `n()` to count the number of observations for each `x`:

```
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#     x n
# 1   . 1
# 2 ing 2
# 3 str 3
```

If you only want those occurring at least 3 times, use `filter()`:

```
df %>% count(x) %>% filter(n >= 3)
```

Which gives:

```
# Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
# 
#     x n
# 1 str 3
```

Finally, if you only want to extract the factors that correspond to your filter criteria:

```
df %>% count(x) %>% filter(n >= 3) %>% .$x

# [1] str
# Levels: . ing str
```

---

As per suggested by @David in the comments, you could also use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(.N >= 3) x, by = x]$V1
```

Or

```
setDT(df)[, .N, by = x][, x[N >= 3]]

# [1] str
# Levels: . ing str
```

As per suggested by @Frank, you could also use `table`'s "workhorse" `tabulate`:

```
levels(df[[1]])[tabulate(df[[1]])>=3]

# [1] "str"
```

---

**Benchmark**

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(LETTERS[1:26], 10e6, replace = TRUE))
df2 <- copy(df)

library(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  base = names(which(table(df$x) >= 385000)),
  base2 = levels(df[[1]])[tabulate(df[[1]])>385000L],
  dplyr = count(df, x) %>% filter(n >= 385000) %>% .$x,
  DT1 = setDT(df2)[, if(.N >= 385000) x, by = x]$V1,
  DT2 = setDT(df2)[, .N, by = x][, x[N >= 385000]],
  times = 50
)
```

[image]

```
> mbm
#Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
#  base 495.44936 523.29186 545.08199 543.56660 551.90360 652.13492    50    d
# base2  20.08123  20.09819  20.11988  20.10633  20.14137  20.20876    50 a   
# dplyr 226.75800 227.27992 231.19709 228.36296 232.71308 259.20770    50   c 
#   DT1  41.03576  41.28474  50.92456  48.40740  48.66626 168.53733    50  b  
#   DT2  41.45874  41.85510  50.76797  48.93944  49.49339  74.58234    50  b
```

Comment: I wonder how `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, if(.N >= occurs) x, by = x]$V1` performs. Or maybe `setDT(df)[, .N, by = x][, x[N >= occurs]]` (not sure which is better)

Comment: Should be really fast. Let me add it to the benchmark.

Comment: When adding, don't run it on the same data set. Create `df2 <- copy(df)` and then run the `data.table` benchmarks on `df2`. Otherwise, `setDT` will convert `df` to `data.table` on the first iteration for *all* the other functions too.

Comment: I don't think I would care about speed for this operation,  but base wins on my computer: `base2 = levels(df[[1]])[tabulate(df[[1]])>385000L]`

Comment: @Frank Yes, `table`'s "workhorse" `tabulate` is indeed *much* faster. I updated the benchmark accordingly.